# Why doesn't any constructor get called?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor, copy-elision

```
class X {
public:
    X() {}
    X(const X&) {
        std::cou << "copy constructor";
    }
    X(X&&) {
        std::cout << "move constructor";
    }
};

X func() { return X(); }

int main() {
    X x(func()); // nothing is printed
}
```

I think that the move constructor must be called, but neither copy constructor nor move constructor gets called. Is this because of copy ellision?

Comment: I _highly_ recommend using more descriptive variable names.

Comment: Can you put some print statement in constuctors and post a link to the online complied code?

Comment: Added std::cout

Comment: @beginpluses Put some print in the default constructor. It will be called. There is elision of the move and copy constructors but one of them shall be acceptable.

Comment: I'm interested only in copy and move constructors. Default one is called, ofcourse

Comment: "Why doesn't any constructor get called?"  This `X() {}` is a constructor.  It gets called.